# Cant use $_GET in the jQuery.load-file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm making a teamchat with the help of jQuery and PHP (and I'm new to jQuery btw) and have almost succeeded, except for one thing.

I have 4 files.

- teams.php (which would have the $_GET-info)
- teamchat.js (The jQuery-file which loads messages and updates when
  someone makes a post)
- teamchat.post.php (Inserts the new message to the database)
- teamchat.load.php (Loads all the messages)

Everything works fine except for the teamchat.load.php-file because I have to fetch the messages "WHERE tid = $_GET['tid'] (where tid stands for team-id), but it only says Undefined index: tid.

The code for the jQuery.load() is simply:

```
$('.teamchat').load('./inc/teamchat.load.php');
```

I understand why **but I don't know how to get it to recieve the $_GET information which the teams.php would have (For example teams.php?tid=31)**, and that's why I'm stuck.

What should I do? Is there even an answer to this?

EDIT: Never mind. I'm dumb. Just passed the teamchat.load.php into a function and rewrote the jQuery.load() to

```
$('.teamchat').load('teams.php');
```

Comment: You need to pass the id in the URL in the load request. It's not passing itself from the "parent site" automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"./inc/teamchat.load.php" is not url.

```
absolute url: http://domain.com/file.php
relative url: /file.php or file.php not start with . or ./
```

Comment: Yes, I said I need the variable from the teams.php.
"but I don't know how to get it to recieve the $_GET information which the teams.php would have (For example teams.php?tid=31),"

Comment: in jquery load function: $('.teamchat').load('./inc/teamchat.load.php?tid=23'); use $_GET method and $('.teamchat').load('./inc/teamchat.load.php',{tid:123}); use $_POST method

Comment: But it's the /inc/teamchat.inc.php which have the sql-query and loops the results? Should I change that?

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you mean the GET variables that are on the page where your javascript is being executed:

```
var getString = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1);
$('.teamchat').load('./inc/teamchat.load.php?' + getString );
```

Untested, but i'm guessing this would work.

Comment: Add it to the uri in load.. './inc/teamchat.load.php?tid=123&' + getString. The tid bit was just an example though, so the version above will simply append all GET variables from the page to the ajax request.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just do PHP here? `$('.teamchat').load('./inc/teamchat.load.php?tid=<?php echo $_GET['tid'] ?>');`

Comment: 1> asuming tid is the only GET variable to use. 2> asuming his javascript is not in a template, which would mean php is not available. 3> why? .. you can access the GET variables just as easy with javascript. Hardly makes a difference.

Comment: It's not the teamchat.load.php?tid= I need. It's the teams.php?tid=
I need to pass into the sql-query in the teamchat.load.php-file

Comment: In the teamchat.load.php: 
mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT T1.message, T1.sent, T2.username, T2.uid FROM `team_chat` AS T1
         INNER JOIN users AS T2 ON (T1.uid = T2.uid)
         WHERE tid = '*INSERT $_GET-variable HERE*'
         ORDER BY ID DESC");

Comment: So just do: `$('.teamchat').load('./inc/teamchat.load.php?tid=X');` You'll have X as $_GET['tid'] in teamchat.load.php.